# WebLogic Failed to find Resource Adapter jmsra during deployment of a webapp

Tags: ejb, weblogic, jndi, weblogic12c

During the migration of an application from an existing WebLogic 12.2.1 to a new one I am getting an exception when trying to deploy a webapp which makes use of JMS queues.
At the server log the error reads:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: javax.resource.ResourceException: [Connector:199311]Failed to find Resource Adapter:jmsra The application information: my_webapp_name#my_webapp_name#my_webapp_name The JNDI name:java:comp/env/queue/comm at
weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.activate(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:123)
...
Caused By: javax.resource.ResourceException: [Connector:199311]Failed to find Resource Adapter:jmsra The application information: my_webapp_name#my_webapp_name#my_webapp_name The JNDI name:java:comp/env/queue/comm
at weblogic.connector.external.RAUtil.createAdministeredObject(RAUtil.java:301)
```

**queue/comm** exists as a JMS queue and the module that contains it has the same target as the webapp which fails to deploy.

The beans which use the queue have all a definition like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <enterprise-beans>
      <message-driven>
        <ejb-name>BeanName</ejb-name>
        <ejb-class>com.acme.beans.BeanName</ejb-class>
        <activation-config>
            <activation-config-property>
              <activation-config-property-name>destinationJNDIName</activation-config-property-name>
              <activation-config-property-value>queue/comm</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
              <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
              <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
              <activation-config-property-name>acknowledgeMode</activation-config-property-name>
              <activation-config-property-value>acknowledgeMode</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
            <activation-config-property>
              <activation-config-property-name>messageSelector</activation-config-property-name>
              <activation-config-property-value>MESSAGE_TYPE='BeanMessage'</activation-config-property-value>
            </activation-config-property>
        </activation-config>
      </message-driven>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

I have been unable to spot the difference in the configuration of the two WebLogic instances. `wljmsra.rar` is at `wlserver/server/lib` directory of both instances. And there is a connection factory in the same module which reports to be started.

**EDIT 11/07/2019**
I've found the code fragment which references jmra

```
import javax.jms.JMSDestinationDefinition;
import javax.jms.JMSDestinationDefinitions;

@JMSDestinationDefinitions({
        @JMSDestinationDefinition(name = Resources.COMM_QUEUE, resourceAdapter = "jmsra", interfaceName = "javax.jms.Queue", destinationName = "CommQueue", description = "Queue for communication between applications") })
public class Resources {

    public static final String COMM_QUEUE = "queue/comm";

    private Resources() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is raised by a web-app and not from an ejb module. Check your webapp deployment descriptors they should define a resource reference pointing to your jms queue.

Comment: Thanks @emmanuel-collin but if is an error in the webapp, then why the same war can be successfully deployed into another WebLogic instance that, presumably, have the same configuration? There is a minor difference in WebLogic versions. The one where is works is 12.2.1.0.0 and the one where fails is 12.2.1.3.0.

Comment: can you post the complete error message including the stack trace ?

Comment: Hi! The server log can be found [here](http://www.knowgate.com/shared/weblogic_server.log) The the stack trace begins at line 229. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: the solution for me was to remove resourceAdapter="jmsra" from @JMSDestinationDefinitions at Java source code. It seems that WebLogic 12.2.1.0.0 is all right with this property but not WebLogic 12.2.1.3.0 Some documentation suggests that it is deprecated and may have been removed although I've not been able to find any release notes from Oracle on the topic.